# How to link categories between storeviews - Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, category, ce-1.9.1.0

This is a copy of my question in StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006884/how-to-link-categories-between-storeviews-magento. I thought it would be more appropriate in the magento section.

I have created a multistore website with the following structure:

```
-website
--store1.nl
---store1-view
--store2.nl
---store2-view
--store3.nl
---store3-view
```

On the store1 homepage (CMS-page) I'd like to add a category-link to store2, store2-view. I have put the suggested widget link (see below), with a link to the desired category in store2.nl, but it doesn't link to the category store2.nl, it stays on store1.nl. 
The URL even says `store1.nl<someurlcode>__store1-view` instead of `store2.nl<someurlcode>__store2-view`

```
{{widget type="catalog/category_widget_link" anchor_text="Displayed Text" title="Title attribute text" template="catalog/category/widget/link/link_block.phtml" id_path="category/22"}}
```

I'd rather not hardcode the category-links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with a widget out of the box. To do this you have to add your own PHTML file (and possible block class for logic) and either

- [Emulate the store](http://inchoo.net/magento/emulate-store-in-magento/) you wish to link to
- Get the base URL for the other store with `Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK);` and then paste the category path after that

Comment: thanks Sander, I solved it, below I put the how-to in an separate answer

Comment: Great! Looking forward to how you managed to solve it

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question with the help of Sander's answer, I used Store Emulation.

This is what I did:

I copied:
`app/design/frontend/base/template/catalog/category/widget/link/link_inline.phtml`
to
`app/design/frontend/theme/custom_theme/template/catalog/category/widget/link/link_inline.phtml`

renamed the file to: `link_inline_<store_view>.phtml`

and used the following code:

```
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');

//Start environment emulation of the specified store
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation >startEnvironmentEmulation('<store_view_id2>');
// Gets the current store's id
$idPath = explode('/', $this->_getData('id_path'));
$categoryId = $idPath[1];

            if ($categoryId) {
                /** @var $helper Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category */
                $helper = $this->_getFactory()->getHelper('catalog/category');
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
                $cat_name = $category->getName();
                $this->_href = $helper->getCategoryUrl($category);
            }          

?>
<span class="widget widget-category-link-inline"> <a class="level2" a href="<?php echo $this->_href; ?>"> <span><?php echo $cat_name ?></span></a></span>
<?php

//Stop environment emulation and restore original store
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

To get the particular link in `--store1.nl.---store1-view` to link to `--store2.nl.---store2-view` I used the following `block` syntax in a static block used by `--store1.nl.---store1-view`:

```
{{widget type="catalog/category_widget_link" template="catalog/category/widget/link/link_inline_<store_view2>.phtml" id_path="category/61"}}
```

Improvements are welcome.